# Cannot compile "http" rust crate on linux

Tags: linux, http, rust, rust-cargo

I have been developing an [Actix-web](https://github.com/actix/actix-web) server on my PC and Macbook. Recently, I decided to run the server on an Amazon AWS Lightsail linux instance. On both Amazon Linux 2 and Ubuntu 20.04, I run into an error when trying to compile the [http](https://docs.rs/http/0.2.1/http/) crate both when trying to compile it as a dependency for project and when trying to compile it on its own from [source](https://github.com/hyperium/http). Cargo/rustc is able to compile http's dependencies crates without an issue.

On both Linux instances, the only software I installed was rust, build-essential (ubuntu) / make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel (Amazon linux), and git. I assume there is some library or software I need to install so that I can compile this, but I do not know how to get necessary information out of cargo/rustc.

Running `cargo build --verbose` gives me the following error:

```
error: could not compile `http`.Caused by:  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name http --edition=2018 src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -Cembed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=abcdfe6be82028cf -C extra-filename=-abcdfe6be82028cf --out-dir /home/ubuntu/http/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -C incremental=/home/ubuntu/http/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/incremental -L dependency=/home/ubuntu/http/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps -L dependency=/home/ubuntu/http/target/debug/deps --extern bytes=/home/ubuntu/http/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/libbytes-f1a762425ae02815.rmeta --extern fnv=/home/ubuntu/http/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/libfnv-6df950b2addd58cd.rmeta --extern itoa=/home/ubuntu/http/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/libitoa-edca7ecd3046f3fb.rmeta` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
```

Comment: `SIGKILL` could be caused by the process using too much memory and being killed by the kernel. Does your VM have enough memory?

Comment: @apetranzilla I created a new instance with 2GB of memory instead of 512MB and that did the trick!